# How to pass data between two threads spawned by ScheduledExecutorService in Android?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, producer-consumer, java.util.concurrent

I' m trying to implement a producer-consumer pattern in Android via `ScheduledExecutorService`. So, I have created a producer worker thread which loads data from the web site and consumer thread which filters this data. Here is a code snippet for the demonstration of my problem:

```
public void RunPeriodicBackgroundTasks() {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService backgroundTaskExecutor_ = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
backgroundTaskExecutor_.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
   LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result_ = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(lowLevelNetworkOperation_.executeServerCommand(DASHBOARD_INBOX_SENT_COMMAND, params)); 
    }
},1 ,3, SECONDS);
    //AND NOW I CREATE ANOTHER THREAD for the second task
   backgroundTaskExecutor_.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //HERE I WANT To USE result_

    }
}, 1,3, SECONDS);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ConcurrentLinkedQueue here.

In your first `run` method.

```
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<String,Object>> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<String,Object>>();
public void run(){
   LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result_ = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(lowLevelNetworkOperation_.executeServerCommand(DASHBOARD_INBOX_SENT_COMMAND, params)); 

   for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry: result_.entrySet()){
      queue.offer(entry);
   }
}
```

And in your other run

```
public void run(){
   List<Map.Entry> currentEntries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>();
   Map.Entry  entry = null;
   while((entry = queue.poll())!=null){
       currentEntries.add(entry);
   }
   //use it now
}
```

Now you'll notice this violates the producer/consumer pattern because your two threads are scheduled at fixed rates.  Meaning it will periodically wake/run/sleep over and over again.  ConcurrentLinkedQueue does not block so if there are no elements in the Queue it will return null.

If you wanted it to be truely producer/consumer you would instead have the first task scheduled as you have it but the second task would wait on a queue signal to wake up instead.

```
final BlockingQueue<Map.Entry>queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Map.Entry>();

//This is your second run
public void run(){
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        Map.Entry current = queue.take(); //suspend here if the queue is empty until it 1 or more elements
        //use current
    }
}
```